# Gnuplot reducing the frequency of y axis range

Tags: gnuplot

Hello I have a question regarding how to reduce the frequency of y axis range. I have the following plot
[image]

Earlier I have my y range from [0-90] and I somehow reduced it with the help of some nice people comments in this froum. Now I have an issue with too many values in the y range which looks a bit clumsy. So, Is there any possible way to reduce the frequency of the y range?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `set ytics` eg.

```
set ytics <start>, <incr> {,<end>}
```

or

```
set ytics <incr>
```

eg.

```
set ytics 76, 2
```

or

```
set ytics 2
```

To see all the features of `ytics`/`xtics` type

```
help xtics
```

Comment: Well thanks for the  solution !! Is it possible to provide the ytics through some math operations instead of providing the numerical values. I have many plots and it would take much to set the numerical range for every plots.

Comment: Of course, you can use variables and/or expressions as the arguments. Eg. `0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)` ;-)

Comment: Well does the gnuplot already knows the GPVAL_Y_MAX and MIN values or do we have to assign them. I will add my code. I got some error when I tried to implement the command you have mentioned. Please see the code.

Comment: The problem is, that `GPVAL_Y_MIN` and etc... is declared after the first plot. To demonstrate it do the following:
1. Start `Gnuplot`
2. type `show variables all`
(3.  see the variables ;-)
4. plot something, e.g. `sin(x)`
5. `show variables all`
6. Then you can see, there more variables listed, including `GPVAL_Y_MIN`

Answer (score 1):

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#83b300' pt 4 pi 500
set style line 2 lc rgb '#d66c00' pt 6 pi 700
set style line 3 lc rgb '#179c7d' pt 2 pi 200
#
set pointsize 0.5
#
set xlabel '$Time [s]$'
set xrange [ 0:60 ]
set xtics border out 10
set key off
#
set format '$%g$'
set multiplot layout 1,2
set title 'T\_Bottom\_Fz'
unset xlabel
unset label 1
set ylabel '{[kN]}' offset -0.2
set format y '$%g$'
set ytics 0.2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.5
set label 1 '$\cdot 10^{-14}$' at graph -0.02,1.07
plot filename1 every ::3  using 1:($58/1e-14) ls 1title '$Bladed$' with linespoints, filename2 using 1:($58/1e-14) ls 2title '$FAST$' with linespoints, filename3 using 1:($58/1e-14) ls 3title '$OWLib$' with linespoints
#
set title 'T\_Bottom\_Mx'
unset xlabel
unset label 1
set ylabel '{[kNm]}' offset -0.5
set format y '$%g$'
set lmargin at screen 0.6
set rmargin at screen 0.99
plot filename1 every ::3  using 1:59 ls 1title '$Bladed$' with linespoints, filename2 every ::100 using 1:59 ls 2title '$FAST$' with linespoints, filename3 every ::200 using 1:59 ls 3title '$OWLib$' with linespoints
#
unset multiplot
unset output
reset
```

Comment: The problem is, that `GPVAL_Y_MIN` and etc... is declared after the first plot. To demonstrate it do the following:
1. Start `Gnuplot`
2. type `show variables all`
(3.  see the variables ;-)
4. plot something, e.g. `sin(x)`
5. `show variables all`
6. Then you can see, there more variables listed, including `GPVAL_Y_MIN`